# How to limit folder depth?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I would limit the folder depth in a Sharepoint 2010 document library. E.g.: When the user reaches the 3rd level of depth, he cannot create one more level.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following blogpost explains how to do this by using an EventHandler:

http://browse.feedreader.com/c/Techardinal_SharePoint_Blog/11069981